# group by with another row aggregate function

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, aggregate, postgresql-9.4

I am trying to get the max salary from the department column but I also
want to know the person in that certain department.

what can I do here?

```sql
create table if not exists employee(
    id serial unique,
    firstName varchar (15),
    lastName varchar(15),
    department varchar (20),
    salary int
);

select department, max(salary) from employee
group by department
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get top 1 row of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group)

Comment: @Stu the dup isn't for postgres

Comment: @LukStorms the same principle applies, in fact the accepted answer almost identical to yours :)

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: Postgres 9.4 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculate a rank that sorts by descending salary.
The top 1 will have rank 1 then.

```
select department, salary, firstName, lastName
from
(
    select department, salary, firstName, lastName
    , dense_rank() over (partition by department order by salary desc) as Rnk
    from employee 
) q
where Rnk = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

PostgreSQL has a nifty `distinct on` syntax you can use:

```sql
SELECT   DISTINCT ON (department) * 
FROM     employee
ORDER BY department ASC, salary DESC
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/a6534c/4/0)